# Does it seem right to calculate fractional powers by walking steps method?

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic, exponentiation

We know that $x^y$ means $x$ multiplied by itself $y$ times or $x$ taking $y$ steps.

Is this method suitable when $y$ (the power) is **fractional**?

**e.g.**
if $x=2$ and $y = 3.5$,
we would have
$$2^{3.5} = (2 \times 1) \times (2 \times 1) \times (2 \times 1) \times (2 \times 0.5) = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 1 = 8$$

The result is
$2^3 = 2^{3.5}$ (not possible)

I can't get the reason for it being the **wrong method of calculating fractional powers.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't go something like this: 2 ^ 0.5 = 2 ^ (1/2) = 1.414... The question is why is it wrong to use walking steps method. There should be a reason.

Comment: You don't multiply by half of $x$, you do "half a multiplication".  That is, you multiply by the square root of $x$.  $x^{1/2}$ is defined so as to preserve the law of exponents $x^ax^b=x^{a+b}$ so we need $x^{1/2}x^{1/2}=x$ or $x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @saulspatz the question then would become when $ x^y $ is defined for integer powers as **x** into **x** **y** times, why is it not defined for fractional powers the same way?

Comment: Because of the pure coincidence that $a^1 = a \times 1$, which is just a weird fact about the number $1$. That doesn't give you justification to assert the same thing about the number $1/2$.

Comment: $x^y$ does **not** mean "$x$ multiplied by itself $y$ times". If you multiply $x$ by itself **once** you get $x^2$, not $x^1$. And if you multiply $x$ by itself a hundred times, you get $x^2$ every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't even work for integer values. If it did we would be able to calculate $2^1$ by taking two "half-steps", i.e. $2^1\overset{?}{=}(2\times 0.5)\times(2\times 0.5)=1$.

This doesn't work because halving $x$ is only the right thing to do if you wanted to *add* half a time. It's not right for *multiplying* half a time. But we can make this idea work by taking logs, which reduces multiplying to adding. Now we get

$$\log (2^{3.5})=\log 2+\log 2+\log 2+0.5\log 2,$$
which is correct - and clearly different to $3\log 2=\log 8$.

So basically the issue is that (except for specific values of $x$), $0.5\log x$ is not the same as $\log (0.5x)$.

Comment: Your answer make sense. I am marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

$2^n$ does not mean $\underbrace{(2\times 1)\times(2\times 1)\times\cdots\times(2\times1)}_{n\text{ times}}$ more than $2\times n$ means $\underbrace{(2+0)+\cdots+(2+0)}_{n\text{ times}}$: it is certainly true, but it's the kind of truth which may confuse talented cricket players.

For $n\in\Bbb N$, by definition $2^n=\underbrace{2\times\cdots\times2}_{n\text{ times}}$, and therefore, if anything, the relevant distributive identity is $2^{n+m}=2^n\times 2^m$, which would then become $2^n=\underbrace{2^1\times\cdots\times 2^1}_{n\text{ times}}$. Preservation, if possible, of this distributive property hints towards having $2^{-n}$ be the multiplicative inverse $2^n$ (so that $2^n\times 2^{-n}=2^{n+(-n)}=2^0=1$) and having $2^{0.5}$ be the (positive) real number such that $2^{0.5}\times 2^{0.5}=2$.

Comment: As it is explained in a comment above $ a^1 $ = $ a.1 $ is a co incidence. i.e. Taking power **y** and multiplying **y** is not always the same e.g. $ 3.2 $ != $ 3^2 $. The rate of change is much higher for a power than a multiplier.

Comment: $ 3.2 = 3 + 3 $ but $ 3^2 = 3.3 $

Comment: @ShiranAbbasi I was under the impression that you were the one in need to be told that, seeing as you have put some considerable effort into stating $2^n=\underbrace{(2\times1)\times\cdots\times(2\times1)}_{n\text{ times}}$ in your own post.

Comment: You are right i was in need but by reading answers and comments, i got intuition. Thank you.